# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'response' before initialization

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I'm making an axios post request in my  block but it is giving me this error.  I understand the cause of the error but I don't understand why it is happening.  This is the code that is causing the error

```
let response = Axios.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/threads', {}, {headers: headers})
  .then(thread_id = response.data.id);
```

As I understand it it should not be executing that thread_id assignment until after response has been initialized.

I have searched around on the internet and all I keep coming up with is people explaining the cause of the error.  I know the cause of the error just not why (or even how) it is happening in this instance.

I've also tried adding in the catch block to check that axios was not throwing errors and causing response to not initialize but all I got was the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with you code is that you're accessing `reposnse` without defining it in the `then` block, what you want is probably this:

```js
Axios.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/threads', {}, {headers: headers})
  .then(response => thread_id = response.data.id);
```

Alternatively you can use `async await` syntax as following:

```js
let response = await Axios.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/threads', {}, {headers: headers});

thread_id = response.data.id;
```

Comment: ok so I need to treat the then block as a completely new callback function with it's own scope.  I normally use the older options API so variables are all class level and referenced with this